# Sorting calender items by Title - SharePoint 2013 - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to sort calendar views by Title? May be jquery or javascript way. I have a calendar with 9 overlays. it's looking all good but now users wants to see the event by title. Is it even possible using OOTB or JS? I created a welcome page and dropped the calendar there (via add webpart - app - calendar). I added a CEWP and referenced following sortbytitle.js. looks like the sortbytitle.js is not showing up in the developer tool. I added an alert and is not poping the alert either. Any idea?

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://intranet/15/_layouts/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://intranet/_layouts/15/jquery/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('test');
        var arr = [];
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query>",
            QueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><RowLimit>3</RowLimit></QueryOptions>",
            listName: "SalesCalendar",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                    var dateTempOne = new Date($(this).attr("ows_EventDate"));
                    dateTempTwo = dateTempOne.getTime();
                    arr.push({
                      title: $(this).attr("ows_Title")
                                  });
               });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried editing the web part, and editing the current view and provide the sorting in the view?

Comment: @AlexChance: Good point Alex but calendar type view does not offer sort.

Comment: Wow that's unfortunate. I did not realize that. -1 for SharePoint and Microsoft (again....).